# Android: Add footer to horizontal custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, horizontal-scrolling

I am developing an application in which i am using the horizontal list view with custom adapter. I implemented the horizontal list view using a library got from following link.

[Horizontal List View](http://profi.co/android-horizontal-list-view-library-with-item-scroll/)

This works fine. As i am able to see the horizontal list view and i also able to apply action on tap of list item.

**The issue is:** I want to apply footer view to the list view i implemented with the help of link and library. and when the footer is visible then i want to call a web service to get data from server. I also applied the onScrollListener() on the following list.

The onScrollListener() is working fine. I am also able to call web service when last item appears. But my web service calls before my last item is completely visible, on partial visibility of last item my web service gets call. Also if i scroll the list a little bit then too in opposite direction the web service calls again.

What should i do to **call web service** when my last item of above list is **completely visible** or to add **footer to above list**.

I tried normal way to add footer as :

```
footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_footer_view, null, false);
twoWayListView.addView(footerView);
```

but it gives error.

```
03-10 14:37:05.173: D/ACRA(23881): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881): com.example.demolist fatal error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demolist/com.example.demolist.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demolist/com.example.demolist.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881): Caused by:     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:452)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at com.example.demolist.MyActivity.initializeScreen(MyActivity.java:100)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at com.example.demolist.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:73)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
03-10 14:37:05.178: E/ACRA(23881):  ... 11 more
03-10 14:37:05.178: I/ACRA(23881): Finishing the last Activity prior to killing the Process
03-10 14:37:05.186: I/ACRA(23881): Finished class com.example.demolist.MyActivity
03-10 14:37:05.186: I/Process(23881): Sending signal. PID: 23881 SIG: 9
```

Please suggest me what should i do.

Comment: `twoWayListView.addView(footerView);` You can't add a view in a list like that. You need an adapter for that! Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27699592/3531756)

Comment: @Tushar: I am having custom adapter which i am setting after addView() method.